# Swift/Xcode6: "found nil unwrapping optional" for my user's location

Tags: xcode, swift, geolocation, option-type

So I'm experiencing an odd error - `"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"`...

It's strange because it only ever fails the **FIRST** time I run the simulator. As long as I don't quit the simulator and just re-run the app, it will not fail, and the user location will be found successfully. If I do quit the simulator and then try to re-run the app, it will fail with the same error.

Why is this happening? Is swift somehow checking for a location before it's actually found?

Thanks in advance.

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery! {

    let query = PFQuery(className: "Yak")
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.delegate = self // ? delegate
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()


    var userLocation:CLLocation = manager.location 

    currLocation = userLocation.coordinate // error occurs here        

    println(" my location is \([manager.location])")

    if let queryLoc = currLocation {
        println("ahahahaha")

        query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint:PFGeoPoint(latitude: queryLoc.latitude as CLLocationDegrees!, longitude: queryLoc.longitude as CLLocationDegrees!), withinMiles: 10)
        query.limit = 200
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")

    }
```

Comment: On which line does the error appear?

Comment: "var userLocation:CLLocation = manager.location"

Comment: Where is initialized "manager"? And from where are you calling the queryForTable function?

Comment: all of this is happening in my TableViewController. I initialized "manager" at the top of my controller, right after setting the "TableViewController" class.

Comment: let manager = CLLocationManager()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are trying to retrieve data coming from an asynchronous service using a linear procedure.

As this line implies:

```
manager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

the manager is starting to update the location, but it doesn't mean when it returns a location has already been obtained. It can take some time time, and it can also fail.

The right place to read the location is in the `didUpdateLocations` method of the`CLLocationManagerDelegate`, which I presume you have set in the view controller.

The reason why it works the 2nd time you use it is because in the previous run the manager did have the time to detect the location, so what you're getting is the old one, and not an up to date location.

**Update**

One possible way of solving the problem is:

- in `viewDidLoad` check if `userLocation.coordinate` is not nil (it's an implicitly unwrapped optional, so you can do that check)
- if it's nil, start updating the location, add a `UIActivityIndicator`, maybe disable user input, and set a flag (instance property) to true, to keep track you're waiting for a location
- wait for a location to be obtained in `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)`
- in that method, check if the flag is true, if it is, unset it, remove the progress view and re-enable user input, then call `queryForTable`